# How to iterate a gridview by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Suppose my gridview has a few rows and every row has a few textboxes. I want to iterate the gridview with JavaScript to read the value of each textbox. How easily can I achieve it by plain JavaScript or jQuery? I want a cross browser solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely use jQuery. I use a couple of different [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) below. This should give you a general idea of how to accomplish your goal.

```
$('#gridviewId').find('.textClass').each(function () { alert($(this).val()) });
```

The above code would use the grid view's id and then would find all of the descendant elements with a particular class (in your case textboxes) alerting their value. I've added a working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/GWAAC/.

Comment: ASP mangles IDs. I recommend adding a class to the control with the `CssClass` property and using it `$('.gridviewClass')` rather than `$('#gridviewId')`.

Comment: @Just808 agreed, the other ASP.NET friendly solution is to use a begins with `[id^=viewId]` or ends with `[id$=viewId]` attribute selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: how to iterate in all rows in gridview without using class. please show a sample. thanks.

Comment: @Thomas `$('#gridviewId').find('tr')` would find all of the rows in the grid view.

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery. If you know the class or ID of the elements you need, a simple [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/) will return all of them